# Next.js: Objects with toJSON methods are not supported while passing props to Client components

Tags: next.js, sequelize.js, server-side-rendering, react-server-components

I am fetching some data from MySQL database using Sequelize ORM in Next.js App router. This is what my method "*getTransactions*" returns:

```js
const { rows, count } =  await Transaction.findAndCountAll({
    limit,
    offset,
    where: whereClause,
    order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
});

return {
    items: rows,
    totalItems: count,
    totalPages: Math.ceil(count / limit),
    currentBalance,
};
```

While passing this data to client component, I get the following warning in the console:

**Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Objects with toJSON methods are not supported. Convert it manually to a simple value before passing it to props.**

Server Component:

```js
const data = await getTransactions({ page, limit, query: search });
return (
    <TransactionsTable response={data} />
);
```

Client Component:

```js
const TransactionsTable = ({ response }: { response : PaginatedTransactions | null }) => {
    //TSX
}
```

I tried to serialize and deserialize the data and made sure the timestamps (created_at and updated_at) are converted to Dates before sending to the client component. Now, it works fine and no warning is logged to the console. But I do not get the point of doing this additional stuff.

```js
const data = await getTransactions({ page, limit, query: search });
const serialize = JSON.stringify(data);
const deserialize = JSON.parse(serialize, (key, value) => {
    if (key === "created_at" || key === "updated_at") {
        return new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
}) as PaginatedTransactions | null;

<TransactionsTable response={deserialize} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you encountered this error is because only following things can be passed down to a client component and vice versa:

- Plain objects and promises
- Strings
- Numbers
- Booleans

The values you are simply "passing" to the client component from your perspective are in reality sent over the network and thus need to be serializable.

```js
// this does not work
export default async function ServerComponent() {
  const response = await fetch("..");
  return <ClientComponent data={response} />;
}

// this does work
export default function ServerComponent() {
  const promise = fetch("..");
  return <ClientComponent data={promise} />;
}

// this does work too
export default async function ServerComponent() {
  const json = await (await fetch("..")).json();
  return <ClientComponent data={json} />;
}
```

An exception to this paradigm are server actions that can be passed to client components (even if a kind of function too) but similarly to the previously mentioned behavior they only can accept the same type of values as function parameters that client components can via their props.

Comment: I am fetching data from the database. Is there any other way to get around in TypeScript?

Comment: It does not matter where you are fetching your data from, same conditions apply.